# Unable to animate a horizontal line vertically up and down

Tags: css, reactjs

**Problem faced:** Unable to create a horizontal line that moves up and down (vertically) for a scanner-like feature.

**What I've tried:** I've searched online for horizontal line animation code and saw this code which causes the horizontal line to move sideways instead. I'm not sure how to change the horizontal line movement from sideways to vertical.

**What I need:** If the code below could be modified to achieve a vertical movement instead or any other readily available code that could demonstrate that movement, that would be great.

Here's the code I saw online (sideway movement):

```
<!-- horizontal line moves sideways -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content=
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
    <title>
        How to animate a straight
        line in linear motion?
    </title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: green;
        }

        .geeks {
            width: 400px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .geeks::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: green;
            animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes animate {
            0% {
                left: 0;
            }

            50% {
                left: 100%;
            }

            0% {
                left: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="geeks"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen has tons of examples.

For instance this one: https://codepen.io/dicson/pen/eGZOYq

Or this one: https://codepen.io/branovaclav/pen/bpobbg

Code:

```
<div class="fingerprint scanning"></div>
<br>
```

```
.fingerprint {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border: solid 3px #AAB8BE;
}

.fingerprint.scanning::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 58px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    rgba(170, 184, 190, 0),
    rgba(170, 184, 190, .8));
  animation: scanning .8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scanning {
    100% { transform: translate(0, 52px); }
}
```

```css
.fingerprint {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border: solid 3px #AAB8BE;
}

.fingerprint.scanning::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 58px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    rgba(170, 184, 190, 0),
    rgba(170, 184, 190, .8));
  animation: scanning .8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scanning {
    100% { transform: translate(0, 52px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="fingerprint scanning"></div>
<br>
```